# Launch an activity from a different class

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-asynctask

I am trying to launch an activity in the onPostExecute method of an AsyncTask. This async class is implemented in another class which **dosent extends an activity**. But I am passing application context as an argument to the method in this class.
Here is the sample code

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
        {
            try
            {
                System.out.println("Response : "+result);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Account Successfully Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(context,OperationPanelActivity.class);
                context.startActivity(intent);
             }
             catch(Exception e)
             {
                   Log.d("Error: ", e.getMessage());
             }
        }
```

Inside this class I am taking the application context like this

```
public void createUser(String userName,String password,String firstName,String lastName,String email,Context context)
    {
        InvokeWebService service = new InvokeWebService();
        CALL_URL = Global.SERVICE_URL+"createuserget";
        this.context = context;
        service.execute(new String[] {userName,password,firstName,lastName,email});
    }
```

But the new activity is not getting invoked.

How can I do this in android?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your activity could be finished by the time you run onPostExecute. You should notify the activity somehow and let the activity start the new activity

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I am new to android could you please explain bit more. Thanks

Comment: option A : you put your asynctask in your activity (it is bad) option B, there are like 100 communication systems (content observers, notification manager, messages and handlers, service binding) you can use to tell the activity the job is done. most likely, your asynctask will be in a service, so your activity should bind this service.